Deactivating the render checkbox of status bar with PyQGIS
I was wondering whether it is possible to activate/deactivate the Render function of the QGIS canvas:

I searched everywhere online but I found nothing even about the function itself.

This checkbox is a part of the QGIS's Status Bar. It could be accessed via the QgisInterface class and its corresponding statusBarIface()-method:

Returns a pointer to the app's status bar interface.

The following piece of code should do the job:
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface

# accessing the status bar instance widget
status_bar = iface.statusBarIface()

# accessing the render checkbox object
render_checkbox = status_bar.findChild(QCheckBox, 'mRenderSuppressionCBox')
if render_checkbox.isCheckable() and render_checkbox.isChecked():
    render_checkbox.setChecked(False)


Works like a charm, thanks a lot!!!
